# Get Public URL for File - Google Cloud Storage - App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-storage

Is there a python equivalent to the getPublicUrl [PHP method](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/)?

```
$public_url = CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl("gs://my_bucket/some_file.txt", true);
```

I am storing some files using the Google Cloud Client Library for Python, and I'm trying to figure out a way of programatically getting the public URL of the files I am storing.

Comment: I don't think that has been added to the python API - you can file a feature request in the issue tracker to get it added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel, Isaac - Thank you both.

It looks to me like Google is deliberately aiming for you not to directly serve from GCS (bandwidth reasons? dunno). So the two alternatives according to the docs are either using Blobstore or [Image Services](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/) (for images).

What I ended up doing is serving the files with [blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage) over GCS.

To get the blobstore key from a GCS path, I used:

```
blobKey = blobstore.create_gs_key('/gs' + gcs_filename)
```

Then, I exposed this URL on the server - 
Main.py:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
...
    ('/blobstore/serve', scripts.FileServer.GCSServingHandler),
...
```

FileServer.py:

```
class GCSServingHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self):
        blob_key = self.request.get('id')
        if (len(blob_key) > 0):
            self.send_blob(blob_key)
        else: 
            self.response.write('no id given')
```

Comment: Just to be clear, using `send_blob()` or `images.get_serving_url()` still counts against the more-expensive GAE bandwidth quota, and not the less-expensive GCS egress quota, correct?

Comment: I think get_serving_url produces a url that is GCS direct, and therefore less expensive. It has an additional benefit of applying automatic image resize as part of url parameter

Answer (score 59):

Please refer to https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-uris on how to build URLs.

For public URLs, there are two formats:

```
http(s)://storage.googleapis.com/[bucket]/[object]
```

or

```
http(s)://[bucket].storage.googleapis.com/[object]
```

Example:

```
bucket = 'my_bucket'
file = 'some_file.txt'
gcs_url = 'https://%(bucket)s.storage.googleapis.com/%(file)s' % {'bucket':bucket, 'file':file}
print gcs_url
```

Will output this:

> https://my_bucket.storage.googleapis.com/some_file.txt

Comment: If it's within a subfolder then 'https://my_bucket.storage.googleapis.com/subfolder/some_file.txt'

Comment: As of 2018 the pattern has updated to: `https://storage.cloud.google.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]`  The link above is still valid and includes more info.

Comment: The link in the answer points to https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data, which says to use
`http://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]`

Comment: as of June 19, you cannot do this via gcloud api's in python. I am sure they will have this in the forthcoming features.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [`get_serving_url`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions#Image_get_serving_url) from the Images API. As that page explains, you need to call `create_gs_key()` first to get the key to pass to the Images API.

Comment: You can only use that for image files, not for any type of file.

Answer (score 2):

It's not available, but I've filed [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/issues/detail?id=28).  In the meantime, try this:

```
import urlparse

def GetGsPublicUrl(gsUrl, secure=True):
  u = urlparse.urlsplit(gsUrl)
  if u.scheme == 'gs':
    return urlparse.urlunsplit((
        'https' if secure else 'http',
        '%s.storage.googleapis.com' % u.netloc,
        u.path, '', ''))
```

For example:

```
>>> GetGsPublicUrl('gs://foo/bar.tgz')
'https://foo.storage.googleapis.com/bar.tgz'
```

Comment: The secure version of the public url will not work for the default bucket. It reports a  net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE. But you can use: https://storage.googleapis.com/<default_bucket>/<folder>/<filename>

Comment: Where do you see that?  The certificate I get for https://foo.storage.googleapis.com is valid for *.storage.googleapis.com.

Comment: I have the problem in Chrome and Firefox using the secure link which starts with the bucket. In Firefox I can add an exception. Example: https://jinjacms2.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com/eurocodicil/Disclaimer.pdf