# Retrieving public path using KnpGaufretteBundle with GoogleCloudStorage adapter

Tags: symfony, google-cloud-storage, gaufrette

After setting up the KnpGaufretteBundle with GoogleCloudStorage adapter, I am able to write files in the Google Cloud Storage.

But I have no clue on how to retrieve the public access link to that file (image, in this case).

Here is an example of the code I am using to write, if it is relevant in anyway. Actually I have to versions:

```
$fs = $this->get("knp_gaufrette.filesystem_map")->get("bucket_name");
$fs->write("image.jpg",file_get_contents("/path/to/file"));
```

or

```
$file = new \Gaufrette\File("image.jpg",$this->get("knp_gaufrette.filesystem_map")->get("bucket_name"));
$file->setContent(file_get_contents("/path/to/file"));
```

Any ideas on how to retrieve the public ("http://..") url from here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could get around getting the url programatically.

First I had to make the bucket public like this:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public

An then I got the url following this post:

[Get Public URL for File - Google Cloud Storage - App Engine (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863747/get-public-url-for-file-google-cloud-storage-app-engine-python)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Gaufrette Extra ([gaufrette extra](https://github.com/Gaufrette/extras)).
You should be able to implement it easily by copying the way they are doing it for Amazon S3