# Get Google Cloud Storage object from Public URL of an image

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

The problem I have is the reverse of the one mentioned in this 
question: [Get Public URL for File - Google Cloud Storage - App Engine (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863747/get-public-url-for-file-google-cloud-storage-app-engine-python)

I have the public (serving) URL for an image uploaded to Google Cloud Storage via my Google App Engine Python application.
Unfortunately through a yet undetected bug, a record in my database associating the blobstore key (I used blobstore.create_gs_key) and Cloud Storage object and serving URL, was not created.

Now I need to delete that image and all I have is the serving URL, and I need a Cloud Storage object for that.

Any idea if it is possible to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting the Blobstore Python API on [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-compat-runtime/blob/master/appengine-compat/exported_appengine_sdk/google/appengine/ext/blobstore/blobstore.py) I don't think the API offers an easy programatic method to achieve your specific request.

A possible workaround I could think of is that since you have the [Cloud Storage URI](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints) and most likely know the bucket name to simply search for orphan blobs on the bucket and delete them. You can find an example on the community [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935980/is-it-possible-to-find-and-delete-orphaned-blobs-in-the-app-engine-blobstore).

Finally, I'd like to  advise you to use the [App Engine client library for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage) instead of [Blobstore Python API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/blobstore/) as suggested on this latter documentation.

Comment: Yea, I suspect you are right and what I want is not possible. Searching for an orphan is not really practical - millions of images down there. I do want to rewrite our image server, eyeing new GAE with python 3 and relational database instead of Google datastore.

Comment: That final option would be the optimal way to go taking into the consideration the [deprecation of Python 2 since January 1 2020](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/). Take into consideration that the documentation offers some very useful insights for migrations from Python 2 to Python 3 for App Engine. You can take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/)